# How to query all the information in Firebase in reference-id relationship

Tags: java, android, firebase

I’m building an Android app that contains a feed of videos, like Facebook’s feed page but with Videos. In Firebase I have two root elements “posts” and “videos”  (the following is a simplified version of the data structure).

```
{
  "posts": {
    "postId1": {
      "createdAt": "15/05/2014 15:03:45",
      "section": "trending",
      "type": "videoPost",
      "videoId": "7hPMmzKs62w"
    },
    "postId2": {
      "createdAt": "15/05/2014 11:03:45",
      "section": "home",
      "type": "videoPost",
      "videoId": "Lp9GgdCgMXk"
    }
  }
  ,
  "videos": {
    "7hPMmzKs62w": {
      "credits": "The War on Drugs",
      "duration": "2:53",
      "title": "Red Eyes"
    },
    "Lp9GgdCgMXk": {
      "credits": "Shamir",
      "duration": "2:57",
      "title": "On the Regular"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see each post is related to an specific Video. Each post has a videoId property that holds the id of the video. I came up with this design to avoid duplicating the video’s information on both the video and on each post.

In my app, I have two classes PostFB and VideoFB in order to hold the post and video information. Each PostFB object has a reference to  a VideoFB object. In order to get all the posts and their corresponding videos I use the getPosts method in the following class.

```
public class DatabaseHelper {
    private int numVideosFetched = 0;

    public final void getPosts(final PostsDownloadedListener listener, String genre) {
        final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://leaffm-dev.firebaseio.com");
        numVideosFetched = 0;
        final List<PostFB> posts = new ArrayList<PostFB>();

        //Query 1: Get the posts from Firebase
        ref.child("/posts").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //The expectedVideosToFetched is equals to the number of posts since each post must have a video                     associated

                final long expectedVideosToFetched = snapshot.getChildrenCount();

                //For each post
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    final PostFB post = postSnapshot.getValue(PostFB.class);

                    post.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                    String videoId = post.getVideoId();

                    //Get the corresponding video using videoId
                    ref.child("videos/" + videoId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            VideoFB video = snapshot.getValue(VideoFB.class);
                            //Set the video to the post
                            post.setVideo(video);
                            numVideosFetched++;

                            //When all the videos have been downloaded, then let the listener know
                            if (numVideosFetched >= expectedVideosToFetched) {
                                listener.onSuccess(posts);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    posts.add(post);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                listener.onError(firebaseError);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I get all the posts and then for each post I read its videoId value and make an inner query to get the corresponding video from firebase. In order to know when all the information have been downloaded I use a counter, to track the amount of videos downloaded or fetched so far. When this count matches the expected number then I let the listener know that the data is ready to be displayed.

Why question is, is there other way to Get all the information in a scenario like this, using reference ids?   Or is this a sign of a bad data design? I’m asking the second question because one option is to flat the data even more and have all the videos’ information in the post, like this:

```
"posts": {
    "postId1": {
      "createdAt": "15/05/2014 15:03:45",
      "section": "trending",
      "type": "videoPost",
      "video": {
          "credits": "The War on Drugs",
           "duration": "2:53",
           "title": "Red Eyes"
         },
     }
```

But my concern is that, at some point, further in the development I’d need to have reference Ids as in the relationship between posts and videos in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding duplicating data isn't necessarily a good thing. It's more work for you to manage it, but the user experience will be much faster if you use a tailored data structure for each use case. You can store the video within the post, with its id as a property if you need to.

```
"posts_with_video": {
    "postId1": {
      "createdAt": "15/05/2014 15:03:45",
      "section": "trending",
      "type": "videoPost",
      "video": {
           "id": "videoID1",
           "credits": "The War on Drugs",
           "duration": "2:53",
           "title": "Red Eyes"
         }
     }
}
```

If you need a reference to just the relationships without the whole post or video, then you can create separate index nodes for that. (Assuming below the relationship is many-to-one)

```
"posts_video": {
    "postId1": "videoID1",
    "postId2": "videoID4",
    "postId3": "videoID1"
},
"video_posts": {
    "videoID1": {
         "postId1": true,
         "postId3": true 
    },
    "videoID4": {
         "postId2": true
    }
}
```

While this looks like a lot to handle, [Firebase's multi-path updates](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html) make managing this very easy.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's for clear for me! I'll follow your advice! The multi-path updates seem very useful!